# Trying to draw an arbitrary background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

I've already seen many tutorials trying to put an image as background of my main activity. Tested many ways, and now I'm with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/library"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bckgrndimg" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="370dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nuevo_libro"
        android:id="@+id/nuevoLibro"
        android:layout_above="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/biblioteca_virtual"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nuevoLibro"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
</merge>
```

Ok, this should go ok, shouldn't it? My "library" image is a 900x600 PNG image, but it just doesn't show up on the screen.

Am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: post complete layout file

Comment: change your Relativelayout layout_height ="wrap_content"

Answer (score 2):

Do you need an Image View?
You could do something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/library.."
    ...
>
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Background color of RelativeLayout

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

To

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```